# Question about the derivation of the general solution to a first-order linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Taking an ODEs class for the first time. Been a minute since I took Calculus, so sorry if this question has a simple answer I'm missing.

I'm deriving the general solution for $\frac{dy}{dt}+p(t)y=g(t)$. I got through the solution for $\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=g(t)$ with $a$ as a constant and understand why the integrating factor is $e^{at}$. In the derivation for the general case with $p(t)$, the textbook states $\mu(t)$ must satisfy the equation $\frac{d\mu(t)}{dt}=p(t)\mu(t)$, which makes sense. Then the texbook states

If we assume temporarily that $\mu(t)$ is positive, we have

$$\frac{1}{\mu(t)}\frac{d\mu(t)}{dt}=p(t)$$

and consequently

$$ln|\mu(t)|=\int p(t)dt+k$$

The second line is the one I don't understand. I assume we're integrating both sides, so where does the $\frac{d\mu(t)}{dt}$ go? How do you go from the first to the second? Again, sorry if this is a simple mistake on my part. Cheers.

Comment: If you take the derivative of the second line, do you see how you get the first? (Recognizing the $\frac{y'}{y}$ pattern, or more generally $y^n y'$, and knowing what to do with it becomes easier with ODE practice.)

Answer (score 1):

It is similar. The equation can be written as:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{y} +p(t)y & = g(t) \\
\end{align}
$$
Take note of the notation $\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt}$.

We can multiply $e^{\int p(t)dt}$ to both sides of the equation:
$$
\begin{align}
e^{\int p(t)dt} \Bigl( \dot{y} +p(t)y \Bigr) & = e^{\int p(t)dt}g(t) \\
e^{\int p(t)dt}\dot{y} + e^{\int p(t)dt}p(t)y & = e^{\int p(t)dt}g(t) \\
\end{align}
$$
This also can be written as an ODE equivalently in this expression:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\Bigl( e^{\int p(t)dt}y \Bigr)} & = e^{\int p(t)dt}g(t) \\
\end{align}
$$
We can let $\mu(t)=e^{\int p(t)dt}$ be the integrating factor.
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\Bigl( \mu(t)y \Bigr)} & = \mu(t)g(t) \\
\end{align}
$$
By integrating both sides, the general solution to the first order inhomogeneous ODE is:
$$
\begin{align}
\mu(t)y & = \int \mu(t)g(t) dt\\
y(t) & = \frac{1}{\mu(t)} \int \mu(t)g(t) dt\\
\end{align}
$$
We can also show that $\dot{\mu}(t) = p(t)\mu(t)$. By differentiating $\mu(t)$ and applying fundamental theorem of calculus I:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\mu}(t) & = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( e^{\int p(t)dt} \Bigr) \\
& = e^{\int p(t)dt}\frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( \int p(t)dt \Bigr) \\
& = e^{\int p(t)dt}p(t)\\
& = p(t)\mu(t)\\
\end{align}
$$
which satisfies the above expression. Hope it helps!